# ERROR in Cannot set property 'value' of undefined when built using "ng build --prod"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Following are the logs using the "ng build --prod --verbose" command.

```
<w> [webpack.Progress] 2995ms building
<i> [webpack.Progress] 13ms hashing
<w> [webpack.Progress] 1434ms chunk asset optimization
Hash: 2c1f0b10337151d9aeac
Version: webpack 4.44.1
Time: 20307ms
Built at: 02/06/2021 8:22:28 pm
                            Asset       Size  Chunks               Chunk Names
             3rdpartylicenses.txt   1.06 KiB
     main.1c4a07f2446ef28bc36c.js  128 bytes       1  [immutable]  main
polyfills.1e08a25bf9e3e2248768.js  130 bytes       2  [immutable]  polyfills
  runtime.5ae786638beeb8e26046.js   1.45 KiB       0  [immutable]  runtime
  styles.98014fe389e74f303238.css   67.8 KiB       3  [immutable]  styles
Entrypoint main = runtime.5ae786638beeb8e26046.js main.1c4a07f2446ef28bc36c.js
Entrypoint polyfills = runtime.5ae786638beeb8e26046.js polyfills.1e08a25bf9e3e2248768.js
Entrypoint styles = runtime.5ae786638beeb8e26046.js styles.98014fe389e74f303238.css
chunk    {0} runtime.5ae786638beeb8e26046.js (runtime) 0 bytes ={1}= ={2}= ={3}= [entry] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.1c4a07f2446ef28bc36c.js (main) 28 bytes ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [0] multi ./src/main.ts 28 bytes {1} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [zUnb] ./src/main.ts 0 bytes {1} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\src\main.ts [0] multi ./src/main.ts main[0]   
chunk    {2} polyfills.1e08a25bf9e3e2248768.js (polyfills) 28 bytes ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [1] multi ./src/polyfills.ts 28 bytes {2} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [hN/g] ./src/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\src\polyfills.ts [1] multi ./src/polyfills.ts 
polyfills[0]
chunk    {3} styles.98014fe389e74f303238.css (styles) 70.6 KiB ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [2] multi ./src/styles.scss 28 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [] css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/styles.scss 70.5 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [+EN/] ./src/styles.scss
 [+EN/] ./src/styles.scss 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\src\styles.scss [2] multi ./src/styles.scss styles[0]

LOG from webpack.buildChunkGraph.visitModules
<t> prepare: 0.1063ms
<t> visiting: 0.1739ms

WARNING in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename 3rdpartylicenses.txt

ERROR in Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
Child mini-css-extract-plugin ../../Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-1!../../Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js??extracted!../../Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ref--13-3!../../Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-4!../../Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\src\styles.scss:
                   Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    3rdpartylicenses.txt  1.06 KiB
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    chunk    {0} * (mini-css-extract-plugin) 73.9 KiB [entry] [rendered]
     [/I9Y] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/styles.scss 71.5 KiB {0} [built]
         ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module uses module.id
         single entry !!C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-1!C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js??extracted!C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ref--13-3!C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-4!C:\Educational\Code\Styling Applications with Angular Material\contact-manager\src\styles.scss  mini-css-extract-plugin
     [JPst] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 2.46 KiB {0} [built]
         [only some exports used: default]
         ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
         harmony side effect evaluation ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js [/I9Y] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/styles.scss 2:0-89
         harmony import specifier ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js [/I9Y] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/styles.scss 3:30-57

    LOG from webpack.buildChunkGraph.visitModules
    <t> prepare: 0.082ms
    <t> visiting: 0.1882ms

ERROR in Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

and my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "contact-manager": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/contact-manager",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "contact-manager:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "contact-manager:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "contact-manager:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "contact-manager:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "contact-manager:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "contact-manager",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}



"@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
```

As mentioned I am not able to build the project using the "ng build --prod" ng command.
I have looked into this but have not found any threads with respect to the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to deploy the app to heroku but unable to do so due to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If not enabled you can try enabling Ivy within your tsconfig.json.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
}
```

If all else fails you can remove `node_modules` directory and do a npm install